# Java annotation that disregards method call if a condition is not satisfied

Tags: java, annotations

Is there a way in Java to make an annotation you put before a method to check if a boolean or any variable is defined/a-certain-value and if it's not it disregards the call to the method (no code from the method will be executed)?

Comment: Are you referring to conditional compilation? You could use the Assert construct but there is no conditional compilation in Java. It's a huge shortcoming, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Annotations just provide metadata about your code. They cannot directly influence your code without the use of tools such as JUnit. As stated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/):

> Annotations, a form of metadata, provide data about a program that is not part of the program itself. Annotations have no direct effect on the operation of the code they annotate.